# Didn't connect to proxy squid. service squid disabled

Tags: server

```
squid.service - Squid caching proxy                                           
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/squid.service; disabled;      vendor prese
 t: disabled)                                                                    
    Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-04-02 14:46:31 MSK; 5min ago         
   Process: 700 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/squid $SQUID_OPTS -f $SQUID_CONF      (code=exited
 , status=0/SUCCESS)                                                             
   Process: 693 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/squid/cache_swap.sh      (code=exited, statu
  s=0/SUCCESS)                                                                    
  Main PID: 701 (squid)                                                          
    CGroup: /system.slice/squid.service                                          
            ├─701 /usr/sbin/squid -f /etc/squid/squid.conf                       
            ├─703 (squid-1) -f /etc/squid/squid.conf                             
            └─704 (logfile-daemon) /var/log/squid/access.log                     

Apr 02 14:46:30 vm116775.local systemd[1]: Starting Squid caching      proxy...      
 Apr 02 14:46:31 vm116775.local squid[700]: 2017/04/02 14:46:31|      aclParseAcce...l
 Apr 02 14:46:31 vm116775.local squid[700]: 2017/04/02 14:46:31|      aclParseAcce....
 Apr 02 14:46:31 vm116775.local squid[701]: Squid Parent: will start 1      kids      
 1491098868.599      0 188.162.229.190 TCP_DENIED/403 4088 CONNECT      i18nmmstat.ucw
 eb.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
 1491098868.609      0 188.162.229.190 TCP_DENIED/403 4088 CONNECT      i18nmmstat.ucw
 eb.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
 1491098868.938      0 188.162.229.190 TCP_DENIED/403 4088 CONNECT      i18nmmstat.ucw
 eb.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
 1491098869.138      0 188.162.229.190 TCP_DENIED/403 4088 CONNECT      i18nmmstat.ucw
 eb.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
 1491098871.758      0 188.162.229.190 TCP_DENIED/403 4064 CONNECT      mc.yandex.ru:4
 43 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
 1491098872.283      0 188.162.229.190 TCP_DENIED/403 4064 CONNECT      mc.yandex.ru:4
 43 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
 1491098873.098      0 188.162.229.190 TCP_DENIED/403 4088 CONNECT      i18nmmstat.ucw
 eb.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
 1491098873.101      0 188.162.229.190 TCP_DENIED/403 4079 CONNECT      www.liquidweb.
 com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
 1491098873.104      0 188.162.229.190 TCP_DENIED/403 4088 CONNECT      i18nmmstat.ucw
 eb.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
 1491098873.529      0 188.162.229.190 TCP_DENIED/403 4079 CONNECT      www.liquidweb.
 com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
 1491098873.589      0 188.162.229.190 TCP_DENIED/403 4088 CONNECT      i18nmmstat.ucw
 eb.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
 @
  "access.log" 52L, 5824C
```